# Error parsing data [Value p of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I'm following a tutorial on how to connect an android APP to a mysql database.
The app has 2 functions : 
Show products (doesn't work)
Create product(works)
When I make a product it successfully registers to the database but I get some errors from my JSOn parser.

I have found a lot of posts dealing with the same problem but I am still having trouble.

E/JSON Parser(1216): Error parsing data [Value p of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject] get_all_products.php

Here's my parser

```
public class JSONParser {


    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }


    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }


        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(19));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data [" + e.getMessage()+"] "+json);
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

}
```

Comment: post the relevant json. looks like response is a string

Comment: Why are you calling `substring` on the JSON `String`?

Comment: Just a note. JSON encoding should be UTF-8 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627, sec 3).

Comment: thanks guys for the answers , the original of this code was : jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());                                                   I I took it from the forum for the substring...

Comment: Okay guys my problem is fixed, my php files had problems... i let some text at the tope of the code(before the <php>). Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, I found out that because I left a `p`
before the PHP file start.